# Why .Net WebClient is able to use HTTPS without any configuration whereas Java HttpClient can't

Tags: java, .net, https, webclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

Don't be surprised but my question is not about something not working: why the .Net WebClient is able to use HTTPS out-of-the-box without any configuration?

I wouldn't ask if I had not some serious reasons to think it should not be the case: indeed I've used the Apache HttpClient to do the exact same operation, a POST through HTTPS, but it complained.

What bothered the HttpClient was the fact the server TLS certificate was not known.
It's a legitimate complaint so I've added the certificate to the JRE certificates store I was using and after that all worked as expected.

First could you remove an horrible doubt: WebClient is correctly using HTTPS and if I try to connect to "https://downloadspywaresandmalwares.com" it should reject me with something like "are you crazy dude, this is not a trusted location!"?

So I guess this has to do with the diverging security policies of .Net and Java: maybe Java is bundled with its own set of certificates and authorities whereas .Net is more integrated with the OS which may have a bigger set of trusted certificates.

So how could I check all these assumptions?

If it can have any importance: I've used the web-site from Chrome but never from IE so WebClient is not using IE configuration.

Thanks for any input. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I've finally got it:

- as I suspected **.Net does not have its own certificates store but uses the OS store**
- I've managed to find and delete the certificate but this is not easy because **Windows is fighting to maintain some certificates** in its store
- once deleted, as expected, the WebClient is broken and complains because it "**Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel**"
- so yes the **WebClient uses correctly SSL**, that's a relief :)

Hopefully this information will be useful for somebody else...